# Create header for DrawerNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to create a drawer. For each screen accessed through the drawer I want to show the same header I am actually customizing on WelcomeContainer AppNavigator. The drawer should overlap the header. The problem is that the header appear only on the home screen: If I click on the the category menu, the drawer disappear. I even tried to copy the header code and past it in the category screen and nothing appeared. This is my code

```
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: WelcomeContainer,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      headerLeft:
      <Icon name="menu" color='#5c72b0' size={35} style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems:'center',
        paddingLeft:10 }} onPress={ () => navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen') } />,
      headerRight: 
      <Icon name="settings" color='#5c72b0' size={25} style={{ alignItems:'center', paddingRight:10 }} 
      onPress={ () => navigation.navigate('Settings', {title: I18n.t('settings.title') }) } />    })
  },
  Settings: {
  screen: SettingsContainer,
  navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
    title: navigation.state.params.title
  })
},
  About: {
  screen: About,
  navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
    title: navigation.state.params.title
  })
}
})



const AppDrawer = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      path: '/',
      screen: AppNavigator,
    },
    Category: {
      path: '/sent',
      screen: CategoryContainer,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
    },
  }
);
```

Could you please help me solve the problem?

Comment: did you try with `headerMode: 'screen'` which cover for entire navigator?

Comment: In the AppDrawer? I tried it right now it dose not have any effect